# Surface area : Volume Ratio

Tags: entomology

[image]I just have a quick question. I am currently studying for a test and I am confused as to what my book is saying. On the first page when learning about the gas exchange of insects it states that the insects have a large surface area : Volume ratio and this increases the rate of diffusion allowing the insects to get the oxygen they need at a fast enough rate to allow them to survive. Then on the next page when talking about the prevention of water loss it states that insects have a small surface area : Volume ratio to prevent water loss as it minimises the area at which the water can be lost. I am confused as the book states that an insect has both high and low surface area to volume ratios and because of this I'm not sure which is correct to write for the exam.

Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome to Bio.SE! Can you provide the exact reference?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your welcome :) I have added pictures of the textbook where it talks about both things and contradicts itself. Inside the rectangle is where it states that small organisms have a large surface area to volume ratio and underneath the rectangle is where it states that the insect has a small surface area to volume ratio. Which statement is correct or am I interpreting it wrong?